# Use the replace function to add a prefix in Select-Object

Tags: powershell

I need to add the prefix of $server to $name.

```
$server = "\\server001"
$array | Select-Object @{Name = "Name"; Expression = {$_.name -replace "`$_.Name","\\\\`$server\\`$_.Name"}}
```

It doesn't work, how can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-replace` uses regex to find a match. It does not need to have characters escaped for the replacement. Also you are escaping the $ with backticks so it would not attempt to expand the variables.

`` "\\\\`$server\\`$_.Name" `` should be this `"$server\$($_.Name)"`

Variables are expanded in double quoted strings. However properties are not with out the use of subexpressions `$()`. Your code is not clear but that would seem like the source of the issue for you.

Comment: Thanks! I used that finally : Select-Object @{Name = "Name"; Expression = {$_.name -replace "$($_.Name)","\\$server\$($_.Name)"}}

Answer (score 1):

That would be a lot simpler if you'd use a format string:

```
$array | Select-Object @{Name = "Name"; Expression = {"$server\{0}" -f $_.name}}
```